# Add multiple primary keys to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, primary-key

I have a table with a primary key available; I want to add another one in primary but can't add it.

| SRNO | TRNDATE | RATE | AMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 08-02-2022 | 120 | 120 |
| 2 | 09-02-2022 | 170 | 170 |
| 3 | 10-02-2022 | 180 | 180 |

I want to add column `Trndate` to the primary key.

When I was try to add in primary following code

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.avgEnt 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_avgent PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (srno, trndate);
```

I get an error:

> Msg 1779, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
> Table 'avgEnt' already has a primary key defined on it.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

When I open the design of table and add primary key `(SRNO, TRNDATE)` then it works fine.

When I was trying to add by using the query, it does not work.

What happened when design windows save that time script i want.

My database version is SQL Server 2014.

Comment: You can't have multiple primary keys in any database product, not just SQL Server. A Primary Key is the *primary* way of identifying a row. `Primary` means first - there can't be two firsts. You can have multiple indexes though

Comment: You can't add a second primary key but you can add a candidate key.

Comment: Perhaps you want a `PRIMARY KEY` and then also 1 or more `UNIQUE INDEX`es?

Comment: Right now I required two primary key in exiting table how can do.

Comment: *"Right now I required two primary key in exiting table how can do."* You don't. End of story. It is not allowed. If you "need" 2 primary keys, then you maybe should have 2 tables, with another table that manages the relationship(s) between the 2 tables.

Comment: "required" by who/what?

Comment: @Larnu I am not add second primary key in list how can I add please suggest me

Comment: I've made 2 suggestions (`UNIQUE INDEX`es and multiple tables), @PiyushKachhadiya . You've ignored them both.

Comment: @PiyushKachhadiya you can't have two primary keys. End of story. The very phrase makes no sense *in English*. You can't have two first things. Besides, the primary key typically controls how rows are stored on disk. You can't store rows in two different ways

Comment: i can't ignore any one @Larnu

Comment: You are not reading comments. You can't have a second primary key, but you can have multiple candidate keys (create an index with not null and unique keywords).

Comment: ok that's mince i can't add in primary key. but I add Unique index right.

Comment: @PiyushKachhadiya you already got answers. You can't have two primary keys. You can have multiple unique indexes or constraints. Try `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_avgEnt_Date  ON avgEnt (srNo,trnDate);`

Comment: Are you trying to create a __Composite__ Primary Key on `(srNo, trnDate)`? You'll have to drop the existing primary key first. Also remember that any Foreign Key references will also need to be Composite Foreign Keys - you won't be able to keep any current foreign keys that only reference `srNo`.

Comment: Do you mean multiple primary keys, or a primary key with multiple columns? Big difference in wording.

Comment: `(srNo, trnDate)` both column add primary key. when i was open table design and add primary it's work fine. but when i use quarry it's not work. @Larnu

Comment: When you do this in the designer, instead of pressing OK, use the script option to generate the T-SQL that the designer GUI pointy-clicky thing will run for you. This will show you that it's not simply "create this primary key instead" but rather drop the existing one and _then_ create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find one solution.

```
select OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS NameofConstraint
FROM sys.objects
where OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)='avgEnt'
and type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT'
```

Find constraint of table `PK_avgent`

After drop primary on table

```
-- drop current primary key constraint
ALTER TABLE dbo.avgEnt
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_avgent;
GO
```

After add two column

```
-- create new primary key constraint
ALTER TABLE dbo.avgEnt
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_avgent PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (SrNo, TrnDate);
GO
```

it is work form me.

Comment: This will `DROP` your existing key and create a new one though; there won't be 2 on the table like your question asks.

Comment: @Larnu yes i was doing this way it's run fine i don't know is it right or wrong please suggest if am i wrong.

Answer (score 4):

A table *cannot* have multiple `PRIMARY KEY`s, this is simply not allowed, there is not work around. It is by design.

A table can, however, have multiple `UNIQUE INDEX`es or `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`s. These are not the same as a `PRIMARY KEY` but do offer similar functionality, and may well provide the solution you need. A column (or set of columns) that are part of a `UNIQUE INDEX` can also be the target of a `FOREIGN KEY`, which if your "need" for a second `PRIMARY KEY` is so you can use it as a `FOREIGN KEY` then this would also fulfil that requirement.

As an example, you might have something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.PrimaryTable (ID int IDENTITY,
                               SomeValue varchar(10) NULL,
                               AnotherIdentifier uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
                               CONSTRAINT PK_PrimaryTable PRIMARY KEY (ID));

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_PrimaryTable_AnotherIdentifier ON dbo.PrimaryTable (AnotherIdentifier);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.SecondaryTable (ID int IDENTITY,
                                 PrimaryID int NOT NULL,
                                 AnotherValue decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
                                 CONSTRAINT PK_SecondaryTable PRIMARY KEY (ID),
                                 CONSTRAINT FK_SecondaryTable_PrimaryTable FOREIGN KEY (PrimaryID) REFERENCES dbo.PrimaryTable (ID));
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.AnotherTable (ID int IDENTITY,
                               AnotherID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
                               OtherValue int NOT NULL,
                               CONSTRAINT PK_AnotherTable PRIMARY KEY (ID),
                               CONSTRAINT FK_SecondaryTable_PrimaryTable_AnotherIdentifier FOREIGN KEY (AnotherID) REFERENCES dbo.PrimaryTable (AnotherIdentifier));
GO
```

So here you can see that `dbo.SecondaryTable` uses the `ID` column of `dbo.PrimaryTable` as it's `FOREIGN KEY`, however, `dbo.AnotherTable` uses the column `AnotherIdentifier` even though it isn't the `PRIMARY KEY`. This is because the column has a `UNIQUE INDEX` on it, meaning that data integrity can be maintained.

Otherwise, as I mentioned in the comments, you could split the table into 2 tables, and then have a 3rd table with a composite key to manage the relationship. So using the `dbo.PrimaryTable` you might have something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.PrimaryTable (ID int IDENTITY,
                               SomeValue varchar(10) NULL,
                               CONSTRAINT PK_PrimaryTable PRIMARY KEY (ID));

CREATE TABLE dbo.AnotherPrimaryTable (AnotherIdentifier uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
                                      CONSTRAINT PK_AnotherPrimaryTable PRIMARY KEY (AnotherIdentifier));
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.PrimaryTableLink (ID int NOT NULL,
                                   AnotherIdentifier uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
                                   CONSTRAINT PK_PrimaryTableLink PRIMARY KEY (ID,AnotherIdentifier),
                                   CONSTRAINT FK_PrimaryTableLink_PrimaryTable FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES dbo.PrimaryTable (ID),
                                   CONSTRAINT FK_PrimaryTableLink_AnotherPrimaryTable FOREIGN KEY (AnotherIdentifier) REFERENCES dbo.AnotherPrimaryTable (AnotherIdentifier));
```

Which you use is up to you. It more depends on your design and requirements. I would likely only use the latter if you needed a many to many relationship, as with a one to one the `UNIQUE INDEX` serves the goal fine. If you wanted to use the multiple table solution for a one to one relationship, you'd likely need to also add `UNIQUE INDEX`es to the `ID` and `AnotherIdentifier` columns on `dbo.PrimaryTableLink`, which poses the question of why didn't you create said `INDEX` on the original column in `dbo.PrimaryTable` first?

Comment: Thanks For answered. your Answered is appreciate, But I Can't Understand When I use Design Windows of Table And Select Both Column And Right Click Add to Primary Then It's Work Fine. But When I Use Quay It's not Work. Why This Happened. I Don't Understand.

Comment: FYI, please don't put a capital letter at the start of *every* word @PiyushKachhadiya ; it makes your language very different to read. Just the first word in each sentence and proper nouns needs the first letter capitalised.

Comment: Sorry for that i was not add capital latter in each word.

Comment: I don't really follow what you're stating in that comment but it reads like you're using the design (in SSMS?). Don't use the designer, it's really not a good tool. Write the T-SQL you need.

Comment: yes same my thinking don't use design (in SSMS) so i write down quarry but not work.

Comment: You mis-interpret what the table designer is doing and that mis-understanding flows into your description which has lead people astray. The designer knows what it retrieved and compares what the schema was to all the changes you have made when you save it. So it knows that your "new" primary key options are a composite key and it drops the old primary key for you before adding your new, single, multi-column primary key.

Comment: Alternatively, the design has an option to "save" a scrpt that you can examine to see exactly what it intended to do. Quite frankly, there are many reasons to not use the designers. Learn to write tsql.

Comment: It's a query, by the way, @PiyushKachhadiya, not a quay or a quarry (these are very different things and you could confuse non-native English speakers or even native ones).

Comment: @Larnu i want a script of design window from (SSMS), like when i was save changes in design windows that time witch script run.

Comment: If you want the script, go to Table Designer -> Generate Change Script, @PiyushKachhadiya . But like i said, learn to write the statements yourself.

Comment: I just share because, i don't know how to do with quarry so share my experience in this.

Answer (score -5):

You can not alter the primary key. The only way is dropping it and then recreating it.

```sql
ALTER TABLE avgEnt DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(srno,trndate);
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/BQuEjw2pthMDb1z8NTdHv/0 check aswell

Comment: This doesn't add a second primary key or index, it deletes one and creates another one